# Adding css style to the element selected with .get( [ index ] )

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add style with `.css()` method to the element selected with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$('.toggle').get(0).css("display", "none");
```

...but that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your HTML, too?

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? Can you use Firebug to prove $('.toggle').get(0) returns an object that you can apply that CSS property to?

Comment: where are you adding css? .try add()  or hide()

Comment: thanks friends! problem is solved!

Answer (score 5):

Is what you want to do

```
$('.toggle').first().css("display", "none");
```

the `.get(0)` returns a DOM object, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery's `.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the plain DOM element.

You should use [jQuery's `.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead when selecting by index.

```
$('.toggle').eq(0).css("display", "none");
```

This will return a jQuery object with the DOM element at the index you specify, so you'll be able to call jQuery methods against it.

Or perhaps better, place it all in the selector using [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

```
$('.toggle:eq(0)')
```

or

```
$('.toggle:first')
```

Also, jQuery has [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods to set the display property. Or perhaps [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is more appropriate considering the class name.

Answer (score 1):

The `.get(n)` function returns the original DOM object. If you want to use this, you can always access the `.style` object and change the CSS properties from there, such as:

```
$('.toggle').get(0).style.display = 'none';
```

or, you can just use the [`eq(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function to grab the n<sup>th</sup> **jQuery** object:

```
$('.toggle').eq(0).css("display", "none");
```

In your case, [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) will also work. You can also always use the selector version of these: `:eq(n)` or `:first`.